# How to dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot

How can you keep different partitions for Windows and Ubuntu.

I'm not sure if I want to switch to full Linux already, so I need to try it before.

Never did it before, can you guide me?

Comment: I want install 8.04 with windows 7 alongwidth.

Comment: 8.04 = offtopic. so please cast a close vote instead of giving FALSE information: 8.04 is riddled with bugs and security issues.  Plus the installation files are gone from the official servers.

Comment: no why offtopic, this is ubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: I looked but my friend give me old copy

Comment: Please use 12.04, 12.10, 13.04 or 13.10.

Comment: 8.04 is 5 years old and have reached end of life. This version is not supported and bugs and vulnerabilities are not fixed anymore. Questions about this version are off-topic in this site. Consider installing 12.04LTS or 13.10.

Comment: I have no money to buy new sorry :/

Comment: IT'S FREE! Ubuntu always has and will be free to use.

Comment: I think you misunderstand - you can donwload the ISO files FOR FREE from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), and then burn the files to a disk.

Comment: then where you buy it free???

Comment: give me the shop name please

Comment: You download the files for free ([here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) is the link again) ), you then need a blank DVD to burn it to.

Comment: aaah yes download. I will tell my friend for the download files

Comment: Also, the disk has a live environment which you can use, to see what it is like before you install it.

Comment: if this question not good move to better site, sry

Comment: Don't Mind... Even though it has a few answers already :-) - e.g. http://askubuntu.com/a/152902/178596

Comment: If you have a blank USB flash drive (1 GB or more) you can use that instead of a blank DVD. You will need a software to create the Live USB from the file. The instructions are in http://ubuntu.com and [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). Thanks @wilf

Comment: Better instrcutions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) as well @user68186

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope this works for you. Upon booting from a live CD:

1. On the Ubuntu Setup screen, hit Enter to Start or install Ubuntu.
2. Double-click Install on the Desktop.
3. Go through the installation wizard (if using Ubuntu 8.04 until you
   reach step 4). Ubuntu 8.10 installs a dual-boot by default
   installation.
4. If using Ubuntu 8.04, then at step 4, select the first option,
   Guided - resize and you can specify how much disk space you want the
   new partition to use as shown below.
5. Continue through the rest of the steps and click Install on step 7.
6. Click Restart Now and remove the CD from CD-ROM drive.
7. Done! Every time you start up your computer now you will be prompted
   to select what operating system you want to start up through the
   GRUB Bootloader screen as seen below.

Comment: Both 8.04 and 8.10 about 5 years old and have reached end of life. These versions are not supported and bugs and vulnerabilities are not fixed anymore. Questions about these versions are off-topic in this site. **Why do you ask OP to install 8.04/8.10?**